# Suppress "WeakerAccess" lint warning on field annotated with @BindView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, butterknife, android-lint

Naturally, ButterKnife fields cannot be declared as private despite of Android Lint not knowing this. However, instead of all my fields looking like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess") @BindView(R.id.foo) Bar mFoo;
```

I prefer the more clean approach

```
@BindView(R.id.foo) Bar mFoo;
```

Ideally I'd like to avoid suppressing the `WeakerAccess` warning for the entire class, or disabling it altogether in my inspection profile, because it is a useful warning.

Is there any way to suppress this warning automatically for any field annotated with `@BindView` in Android Studio?

Comment: appears possible to disable the warning in IntelliJ: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/457